# React function not setting state after being called in constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently making a ReactJS project and I'm encountering the following problem:

Whenever I try to make the function `changeState()` change the App's state by calling it in the constructor it fails to do so. However, if I try to call it in any other place it does change the state.

Here is the code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { elems: [] }
        this.changeState() // This doesn't work
    }

    changeState() {
        this.setState({
            elems: ['new', 'elem']
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.changeState() /* This works */ }
                {this.state.elems}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at the react lifecycle methods.

Comment: Why would call the method in the constructor? (instead of initializing the state to its desired value to begin with?)

Comment: `{ this.changeState() /* This works */ }` will create another problem **infinite loop** check console for detail about error.

Comment: I am hitting an API before setting the state, and that API will be hit multiple times during the program (thus the need for a separate function). I've done a previous tutorial where I was taught to do something very similar to this, and the state actually changed. Thx for the infinite loop info, I didn't know that :)

Comment: Calls to an API should be done in `componentDidMount`. Also, you will get more useful answers if you provide an example that is closer to your actual use case. We cannot know that `changeState` is getting the state from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone facing the same problem, the best solution I found was calling the function in `componentDidMount`, which solved the problem in both not updating the state and the infinite loop caused when called in `render`.

Thanks to all those who helped, and special thanks to both [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) and [Mayank Shukla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5185595/mayank-shukla) for pointing out the issues and helping me find the solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why call the function when you can just have the state set up in the constructor like

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { elems: ['new', 'elem'] }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                 {/* This wont work since changeState will cause an infinite loop because setState triggers a render and render triggers a setState */}
                {/* this.changeState()  */ }
                {this.state.elems}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `constructor` gets called before the component mounts and renders, so you can just set the state directly in the constructor. See the [React Component Lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html).

This is how you should do be setting state in the `constuctor`:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { elems: ['new', 'elem'] };
}
```